# rewrite multiple parameters .htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i need to rewrite www.sample.com/user/john/ to www.sample.com/user/?u=john

this code works only if i leave out the trailing / "www.sample.com/user/john" how do i get it to work like "www.sample.com/user/john/" as well?

> RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_]+)$ index.cfm?u=$1 [L]

now i would need it to function a step further

www.sample.com/user/john/23564/ to rewrite like "www.sample.com/user/?u=john&i=23564"

one thing "www.sample.com/user/john" should still word even w/o the/23564/

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add the optional slash (and the "user/" part of the URL):

```
RewriteRule ^user/([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/?$ index.cfm?u=$1 [L]
```

And the next step:

```
RewriteRule ^user/([A-Za-z0-9_]+)(/([0-9]+))?/?$ index.cfm?u=$1&i=$3 [L]
```

Comment: can you please give more details??

Comment: I just added a slash, followed by a question mark to make said slash optional. 

The segments between brackets can be referred to with a dollar sign, $1 for the first one, $2 for the second etc., I added a second (optional) segment that accepts a slash followed by a number (and a third one that just refers to the number). Does that help?